# How to add seperate iPad and iPhone images in spritebuilder- Cocos2d 3.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I love that Spritebuilder takes the retina iPad image and automatically makes the scaled down iPhone images.

I make one image (ipad retina), And spritebuilder makes the iPhone ones automatically:

But for certain buttons/sprites, I wanted to make both the iPad and iPhone images myself. How do I add custom iPhone AND iPad versions for an image that can be used in the Spritebuilder UI?

Eg. Use one image for iPad (retina), But use another one for iPhone.

Also, how do I add something like an external spritesheet into my Spritebuilder XCode project? (Adding the -hd or -ipadhd suffix no longer works, it just always chooses the one with no suffix) -I heard is has something to do with 'resources-phone'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select an image in SB you can see its preview image in the top half of the file view. Below the image are 4 smaller buttons labelled *auto*, one for each platform (phone, phonehd, tablet, tablethd).

[image]

For instance, select your ipad image, then drag and drop another image to that image's phone and phonehd *auto* buttons. That way they override the original image when the app is run on a phone or phonehd device.

Comment: Thanks, this is an awesome feature, I never noticed it before ;)

Comment: I had to ask the devs myself, it's one of those non-obvious, non-intuitive features with an "Oooh!" moment once you realize how it works and what it does. :)