# Does SpriteBuilder override image override from "auto" or from the right bigger resolution?

Tags: android, ios, spritebuilder

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219884/how-to-add-seperate-ipad-and-iphone-images-in-spritebuilder-cocos2d-3-2) and the following image:

[image]

I know that all images for `tablet`, `phonehd` and `phone` will be taken from "auto" and then "downscaled" if I set it up like that.

But for example, if I override the `phonehd` image, will `phone` image downscale from the "auto", or from `phonehd`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you override an image for a specific resolution, it will only apply to that specific resolution and device type.

Example: If you were to assign an "egg" image to the `tablet` resolution, the egg would only appear on non-Retina tablet (ie iPad) devices. All others would show the metal ball pictured above.